# Split one column into multiple columns in Spark DataFrame using comma separator

Tags: apache-spark, java-8, apache-spark-sql

I want to create a multiple columns from one column from `Dataframe` using comma separator in Java Spark.

I have one value with a comma in one column in `DataFrame` and want to split into multiple columns by using a comma separator. I have the following code:

```
Dataset<Row> dfreq1 = spark.read().format("json").option("inferSchema", "true")
            .load("new.json");

    dfreq1.show(5, 300);


    dfreq1.createOrReplaceTempView("tempdata");

    Dataset<Row> dfreq2 = dfreq1.sqlContext().sql("select split(names, '|') from tempdata");

    dfreq2.show(5, 300);
```

Input

```
+----------------------------+
|                         name|
+-----------------------------+
|ABC1,XYZ1,GDH1,KLN1,JUL1,HAI1|
|ABC2,XYZ2,GDH2,KLN2,JUL2,HAI2|
+-----------------------------+
```

Output

```
+-----------------------------+
| Cl1| Cl2| Cl3| Cl3|Cl4 | Cl4|
+-----------------------------+
|ABC1|XYZ1|GDH1|KLN1|JUL1|HAI1|
|ABC2|XYZ2|GDH2|KLN2|JUL2|HAI2|
+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: split the value based on ',' and getItem by value

Comment: you can save it as text and then read as csv

Comment: Thanks. I am not clear on this. Could you please provide the java code

Comment: @Tamil  do you know upfront the number of columns fixed after split?

Answer (score 2):

> you can try this

```
scala> var dfd =Seq(("ABC1,XYZ1,GDH1,KLN1,JUL1,HAI1"),("ABC2,XYZ2,GDH2,KLN2,JUL2,HAI2")).toDF("name")

scala> dfd.withColumn("temp", split(col("name"), ",")).select((0 until 6).map(i => col("temp").getItem(i).as(s"col$i")): _* ).show
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|col0|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|ABC1|XYZ1|GDH1|KLN1|JUL1|HAI1|
|ABC2|XYZ2|GDH2|KLN2|JUL2|HAI2|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks @Mahesh Gupta. I a using Spark with Java8. If you provide the code in java, it would be great.

Comment: @Tamil i think you just need to change syntax from scala to java it must be Works

Answer (score 1):

```
 List<String> schemaList =  Arrays.asList("name","gender","sale_amount","event","age","shop_time");
    Column column = functions.col("value");
    Column linesSplit = functions.split(column,"@#");
    for(int i=0;i<schemaList.size();i++){
        lines = lines.withColumn(schemaList.get(i),linesSplit.getItem(i));
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You read the csv from this column into a Dataset

```
Dataset<Row> df= spark.read
  .option("header",false)
  .option("inferSchema",true)
  .option("delimiter", ",")
  .csv(originalDF.map(x=>x.getString(0)))
```